# Add-on has a warning that "this script is RC". What does this mean?

Tags: add-on

I was in process of activating the POV-ray 3.7 addon and there was a warning with the message "this script is RC".  What does this warning mean?

Comment: Release Candidate version I assume.

Comment: [This](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RC) was the first link in the list of hits when I googled for "what does rc stand for".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about Blender

Comment: @BlendingJake It is about Blender because add-ons are a part of blender.  Things like bmesh have been adopted and become an integral part of Blender.  So, please clarify how this is not a part of blender as an add-on.  Add-ons are both simple and complex script additions, and script modifications which call external engines to support Blender function.  This is very much a part of Blender's concept.  The add-on exists, it was included with the release; so, I'm not sure what you mean. "Not about Blender"?!  More specifically, it's about the message included in the add-on in Blender.

Comment: Because it is more a question about how a program is released and how its version are labeled, like alpha, beta, RC, etc. This is something that is universal for the most part and not limited to Blender. @Cyberchipz

Comment: Moot: Take something universal like the X,Y & Z axes, universality doesn't imply the lack of  existence of pertinent questions about the X, Y & Z axes in Blender, even if elementary.  I found no constraint rules restricting universality as long as the question pertains to Blender. When did a Warning! become a version? Ans: In Blender. From what I understand, if it exists in Blender, one can form a valid questions barring giving or asking for opinions. Question asked, and answered. I removed the non-compliant opinion request. I suggest the Version: should be 0.0.9 (RC). No Warning!

Comment: +SixthOfFour  "stand for" or "mean"... funny how computers are so literal, it knew what "stand for" means, but didn't know what "mean" ment. This is probably off topic; but it's still funny.

Comment: I only typed "what does rc" and my browser filled in the rest. "what does rc stand for" was the first suggestion, and when I selected it, the link I posted here was at the top of the list. After posting here, I also tried I also tried "what does rc mean", and that same link then showed up as third from the top.

Comment: As much as I think I know about computers & Google; I'm afraid I don't understand why mine didn't.  It does offer completion; and it certainly offers that completion, after I checked out your response. It does seem strange.  'stand for' aren't words I would generally use.  I can find it no problem now, lol.  Of course, there's also now a link to this exact page, if you search for "this script is RC" in quotes, which is 'exactly' what it says in Blender. And it's propagating already on another site. Go figure.  For all I know I typod and didn't know. Too late now.

Comment: I also found a reference here in StackExchange where someone asked, what is it OK to talk about?  And this type question is handled; I'd say entirely.  I wouldn't venture a guess as to why some apparently don't like povRay, I don't know it; but, the thread between a few people with over 10k and I think one with over 100k seem to feel it's included as part of Blender.  I agree. Without mentioning 'it' expressly; but implied by saying all add-ons are acceptable to discuss or ask about.  The purpose is to answer questions related to Blender, creating a repository of answers..

Comment: The OP has posted a question on meta, please feel free to share your thoughts there: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/725/599

Answer (score 7):

RC means Release Candidate that is a final stage of beta version.

[Software release life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)

The warning is added by the Authors of the add-on in its [`bl_info` dict](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Guidelines/Addons), it does not come from Blender itself. Warnings like that are an attempt by the Authors to inform you (the user) about the add-on's state of completion

Comment: I can now find the phrase "this script is RC" when I searched Google; it links to this page.  I'm beginning to understand how StackExchange works!  Thanks for your answer.